# Represent a four letter word as a number

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to do some things in mysql and c++, and I wonder, is there a way to convert a word to a number such that I can recover the word from the value of the number?

Each word represents an ID for a station in a geographic location somewhere in the world.  I am searching for missing values and going to replace using cubic spline, least squares, etc.  But I need to keep track of where to insert the replaced number in the sql table when I am done.  Each word is exactly 4 letters and unique, so I thought that this should be possible.

Comment: Use the correspondence A-$11$, B-$12$, ...

Comment: And then just "glue" the numbers together?  That sounds good.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Also this is better suited for [Cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: How is this cryptography? It's about encoding - that's fundamentally different from encyphering.

Comment: @AlexR This certainly isn't Coding Theory.

Comment: @GitGud Agreed. But even more certainly not cryptography.

Comment: I took the cryptography tag as sayin that the OP's is working with some cryptography where (s)he needs to do this covnersion.

Comment: I originally labelled this as NUMBER THEORY, just so you all know.

Comment: Alright. I think [tag:combinatorics] is the only reasonable tag for this question on this site. You might want to ask such questions at [cs.SE], since they need constructions like this. Or [SO], of course.

Answer (score 1):

One (Standard) way you could do this could be to convert all characters into their respectice ASCII code. So `a` would correspond to `97`. The word cat would be `99 97 116` or `099097116` (insert the two zeros so that each three digits of the number corresponds to a character). The nice things about this is that it is very easy to do in C++. This might not be what you actually want, but since it is unclear what you are trying to achieve, it is hard to give a good answer.

Another way would be to create an array `X[]`  and read a (precreated) dictionary into the array. So that $X[44]$ would be the 44th word on the list.

Comment: How are you going to  decode $44444$? Even your example is ambiguous if you allow non-printable characters.

Comment: @AlexR: The question isn't clear. I am just trying to give the OP an idea of how (s)he might covert between numbers and words in C++.

Comment: And I'm saying that concatenating base-10 representations of differing lengths (1 to 3) is not the way to go, because it's ambiguous. The OP clearly asks for the possibility to "recover the word from the value of the number".

Comment: @AlexR: Ok, I added a bit more.

Comment: Do most computers hold a preceding zero in the front of a number?

Comment: @nonremovable: I think you should update your question to add more detail (context) to what it is you are trying to do. Otherwise it is hard to give anything concrete that might actually be helpful.

Comment: @nonremovable They actually store a 4-"digit" (or 2 or 8) base-256 representation of the number. Thus it may have preceeding zeros, but they don't coincide with the decimal preceeding zeros.

Comment: @AlexR: Base-2 ?

Comment: @Thomas I have updated my question.

Comment: @Thomas Not on a byte-based processor, mate ;)

Comment: @AlexR: You certainly know about this than I do, mate, I thought for a moment that you meant binary was base-256, but that is probably not what you are saying.

Comment: @Thomas What I'm saying is that CPUs work with chunks of 8 bits, representing a single base-256 digit. There is nor low-level way to directly adress a certain bit (base-2 digit) in current PCs.

Comment: @AlexR: You probably know more about this than me, I am a mathematician and not a computer scientist. Binary is base-2 is all I am saying.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way as far as the machine is concerned is to convert your array of 4 ASCII characters (assuming they are one-byte) into an integer simply by casting the pointer to the array of 4 characters into an int pointer and then printing out the dereferenced value of the integer. Then to convert back, read in the integer and make an integer pointer point to it, then convert the pointer to a character pointer and print out the 4 characters as elements of a character array with that pointer. This will work with 8-bit characters and 32-bit integers.

Comment: Wow.  That sounds awesome.  I really wish I knew how to do that haha.

Comment: @nonremovable Look for casting pointers - it's pretty straight-forward in C and co.